# Oracle ADF: Weblogic Maven Deployment: Page shows Plain code after deployment

Tags: java, maven, jsf, weblogic, oracle-adf

I try to build and deploy my application with maven. Everything goes well. But when i am trying to target the url then it just show me the jsf plain code.

What is wrong here? do i miss something?
Notice: If use html code then everything is correct. What could be the problem here?

[image]

login.jsf

[image]

Web.xml

```
    <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>BIGRAPHSERVLET</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>oracle.adf.view.faces.bi.webapp.GraphServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>BIGAUGESERVLET</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>oracle.adf.view.faces.bi.webapp.GaugeServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MapProxyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>oracle.adf.view.faces.bi.webapp.MapProxyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>adfAuthentication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>oracle.adf.share.security.authentication.AuthenticationServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>success_url</param-name>
      <param-value>welcome.jspx</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/adf/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/afr/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BIGRAPHSERVLET</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/GraphServlet/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BIGAUGESERVLET</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/GaugeServlet/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MapProxyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mapproxy/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/bi/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>adfAuthentication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/adfAuthentication</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>JpsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>enable.anonymous</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>remove.anonymous.role</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>trinidad</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>ServletADFFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>oracle.adf.share.http.ServletADFFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>adfBindings</filter-name>
    <filter-class>oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>JpsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>trinidad</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ServletADFFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>adfBindings</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>adfAuthentication</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>If this parameter is true, there will be an automatic check of the modification date of your JSPs, and saved state will be discarded when JSP's change. It will also automatically check if your skinning css files have changed without you having to restart the server. This makes development easier, but adds overhead. For this reason this parameter should be set to false when your application is deployed.</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.CHECK_FILE_MODIFICATION</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>Whether the 'Generated by...' comment at the bottom of ADF Faces HTML pages should contain version number information.</description>
    <param-name>oracle.adf.view.rich.versionString.HIDDEN</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>Security precaution to prevent clickjacking: bust frames if the ancestor window domain(protocol, host, and port) and the frame domain are different. Another options for this parameter are always and never.</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.security.FRAME_BUSTING</param-name>
    <param-value>differentOrigin</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>oracle.adf.view.rich.geometry.DEFAULT_DIMENSIONS</param-name>
    <param-value>auto</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>oracle.adf.view.rich.SYNCROWS</param-name>
    <param-value>enable</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_DECORATORS</param-name>
    <param-value>oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.facelets.rich.AdfTagDecorator</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_RESOURCE_RESOLVER</param-name>
    <param-value>oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.facelets.rich.AdfFaceletsResourceResolver</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>swf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-shockwave-flash</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>amf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-amf</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/pages/login/login.jsf</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/error.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>valid-users</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>adfAuthentication</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/adfAuthentication</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>valid-users</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Are you interested in posting code in images? :)

Comment: I've edited my answer after you posted `web.xml`, check if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this means you are not going through faces filter, you'll need to show us your `web.xml` to be sure.

My guess is that you are targeting the page file directly (because of `/pages` in your url), thus bypassing ADF all together and getting the physical page file as response. Regarding that, it's better to keep all your page files inside `WEB-INF` folder, which is protected, that will prevent anyone from getting actual page code.

**EDIT**

You mapped FacesServlet to `/faces/*`, so try if this URL works: `http://192.168.160.38:7101/on-anspruch-web/faces/login.jsf`